# How to set up a View in Drupal that shows recent posts relative to post date of node it is on?

Tags: views

I want to set up a View that shows all the nodes that were updated within 7 days of the node that is being viewed

So if the node being viewed has a post date of January 15, 2014, I would see posts that were published between January 8-15, 2014.

I know there is a contextual filter involved, but it eludes me how to do this so the date used is relative to the node it is being viewed on.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if possible in Views, but I created a custom block to achieve this.

```
function relative_posts_block_info() {
  $blocks['relative_posts'] = array(
    'info' => t('Relative Posts'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function relative_posts_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'relative_posts':
    $block['subject'] = t('Block Title Goes Here');

    $node = menu_get_object();
    $formatted_date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $node->created);
    $start_date = strtotime('+2 weeks', strtotime($formatted_date));
    $end_date = strtotime('-2 weeks', strtotime($formatted_date));

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'story')
    ->fieldCondition('taxonomy_vocabulary_1', 'tid', $node->taxonomy_vocabulary_1['und'][0]['tid'])
    ->propertyCondition('created', array($end_date, $start_date), 'BETWEEN')
    ->propertyOrderBy("created", "DESC")
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->range(0, 25)
    ->execute();

   $block['content'] = '<ul>';

  foreach($entities['node'] as $obj) {
  $node = node_load($obj->nid);
    $block['content'] .= '<li>' . l($node->title, "node/" . $node->nid) . '</li>';
  }
  $block['content'] .= '</ul>';

   break;
 }

 return $block;
}
```